# Charging a dell inspiron with Dell Extended Battery Life Options software

Tags: dell-inspiron

Would a laptop (Dell Inspiron) using the special windows dell software that prevents the battery from charging fully, it improve life (because it is plugged in 24/7)... once turned off and left overnight, would it charge fully?

Comment: I've got a Dell Alienware from about 3 years ago that also tries to look after its battery. It is always left plugged in, but about once per month it decides to let the battery drain to 40% before recharging it. But the rest of the time the battery is always at 100%. Is your battery management software similar?

Comment: @SirAdelaide you know, I didn't go into it for a long time. I opened the dialog now and it shows it is 100% charged but that "Enable Dell Extended Battery Life" is checked but the settings button is greyed out for it and Desktop and Longevity mode are both enabled. I'm pretty sure before that it was usually not near 100%, which is what prompted me to ask (I have to fly in a couple days and would like to fly with a full charge)